# WCF File Streaming 400 Bad Request

Tags: wcf, httpwebrequest

So I have reviewed a large number of the same issue being reported, and for some reason I cannot get a working version on my end, even using the existing solutions to these questions.  Could someone shed some light on what I am overlooking?  It almost has to be related to the file upload size problem above 64k as I see the error almost instantly as soon as I attempt to pass a file above that size.

Here is the web.config of my WCF Service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
    <sessionState timeout="60" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" executionTimeout="14400"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="FileManager"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="FileManagerBehavior" name="PrimeWebServices.FileManager">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="FileManager" contract="PrimeWebServices.IFileManager"/>
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="FileManagerBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="500" maxConcurrentSessions="500" maxConcurrentInstances="500"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

and here is my WCF Service code behind

```
namespace PrimeWebServices
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "FileManager" in code, svc and config file together.
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class FileManager : IFileManager
    {
        public FileManager()
        {
            HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

            if (httpContext != null)
            {
                httpContext.Response.BufferOutput = false;
            }
        }

        public string UploadStream(Stream stream)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Finally here is the client configuration settings (its a winforms client, using a service reference)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileManager" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:1116/FileManager.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFileManager" contract="PrimeWebServices.IFileManager"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileManager" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

application functions fine as long as the file is under the 64kB limit I see others reporting, which makes me believe that I am just not wiring something up correctly and its failing back to a default configuration setting.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using IIS, and if you have the *Request Filtering* module installed, there is a `maxAllowedContentLength` limit for requests which defaults to 28.6MB. That's what you also need to adjust.

Sample config (setting the limit to 150MB):

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="157286400" />
         </requestFiltering>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

See here for more information: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits

Answer (score 1):

If you use ASP.NET development server, then Streaming mode is not supported. You need to deploy the service to IIS or WCF Service application to use Streaming transfer mode.

Answer (score 0):

In the client settings, make sure the BasicHttpBinding_IFileManager matches the FileManager bindings in the service.